# Avoid validating/ submitting p:selectOneListbox's value completely

Tags: java, jsf

I'm fetching selectItems list for a  `p:selectOneListbox` via ajax using a request scoped bean. Thus on submitting back the form I'm getting this error:

```
j_idt153:j_idt159:j_idt184:j_idt194: Validation Error: Value is not valid
```

I dont want to submit the value of `p:selectOneListbox` to any bean property that's why the value EL for that component was omitted but still JSF is validating the selected option & it is not there since my bean was request scoped. Now I want to completely skip validating this component since this `p:selectOneListbox` is just for presentation purposes & its value is not used after the submit form process. How do I avoid validating/ submitting `p:selectOneListbox`'s value completely

```
        <p:ajax event=".." listener="#{pim.retrieveProjects()}" update="usrProjctsList" />

        <p:selectOneListbox id="usrProjctsList" onchange="jsfElmnt('#{cc.clientId}:selUsrProjct').val($(this).val());">
            <f:selectItems value="#{pim.projects}" var="project" itemLabel="#{project.title}" itemValue="#{project.id}"/> 
        </p:selectOneListbox>

        <h:inputHidden id="selUsrProjct" value="#{bean.underProject}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the error `j_idt153:j_idt159:j_idt184:j_idt194: Validation Error: Value is not valid` referring to `<p:selectOneListbox id="usrProjctsList"` cause its `id` not present in the `j_idt153:j_idt159:j_idt184:j_idt194` id at all...

do `view source` in your browser and look for the `j_idt153:j_idt159:j_idt184:j_idt194` id and try to find out to whom it belongs

also you can try to add `immediate="true"` to your `<p:ajax` to skip validation or try adding `<p:ajax` to that troublesome component `j_idt153:j_idt159:j_idt184:j_idt194`

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, the id doesn't match either. But for skipping the validation you could also use the `process=@this (and other stuff, except the listBox)` on your ajax event. Since you are using primefaces this will just process the stuff written there and skip the rest.